# How to use Poet with Node, Express and EJS template engine

Tags: node.js, express

I discovered the [Poet](http://jsantell.github.io/poet/) blog engine and I would like to know how to use it with the EJS template engine.

Also, even with the documentation, I don't understand how to create new post, in which format, and how it's rendered in the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's an old PR](https://github.com/jsantell/poet/pull/51/files) for examples using EJS instead of Jade. It's pretty much just like the examples in the [examples/ dir](https://github.com/jsantell/poet/blob/master/examples/defaultSetup.js), except just change express' view engine to ejs and use ejs templates instead.