# Setting post title for URL vs display in poet

Tags: node.js, express

Using Poet (https://github.com/jsantell/poet) in Node + Express + EJS (following [How to use Poet with Node, Express and EJS template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482408/how-to-use-poet-with-node-express-and-ejs-template-engine)) and all is working well.  Except for one thing .. how do I specify the title for the URL vs for screen display?

Right now, I have the following directory:

```
./_posts/
    hello.md
    colors.md
    shapes.md
    ...
```

The content of `hello.md` is:

```
{{{
"title": "hello",  // works, but fails if I change it to "Hello World!"
"tags": ["first", "try"],
"category": "javascript",
"date": "7-13-2014"
}}}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico dicta volumus pri cu ..</p>
```

I assume that since the file is titled `hello.md` that I would access it via the route `http://localhost:3000/post/hello`.

This works ... but if and only if the the JSON specifies `{ "title":"hello", ...}`.

If I change the title to say, `{ "title":"hello-world", ...}` then the post is found at `http://localhost:3000/hello-world` and that's what shows up rendered on screen.   And if I set it to "hello world" then I can't even access the URL using `%20`.

What might I be doing wrong on the setup?

The reference site seems to work as one would expect. For instance, `http://jsantell.com/post/browser-dance-party` is specified by the file [browser-dance-party.md](https://github.com/jsantell/jsantell.com/blob/master/_posts/browser-dance-party.md), which specifies a human-readable title.

```
{{{
  "title" : "Browser Dance Party at HTML5 Dev Conf",
  "tags" : ["speaking", "web audio", "dsp"],
  "category" : "web audio",
  "date" : "1-24-2014",
  "description" : "Browser Dance Party talk at HTML5 Dev Conf"
}}}
```

Comment: The package author posted the (answer on GitHub)[https://github.com/jsantell/poet/issues/100#issuecomment-48993890].  The default rule is to convert spaces to dashes and strip out other non-alphanumerics, and can set a `slug` property explicitly.